# Cannot find Tools.jar

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to build a copy of JOGL

but ant keeps giving me the error cannot find tools.jar.

so i searched within my JDK dir and i also cannot find it. can someone help me with locating tools.jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you're searching your *JDK* directory instead of the *JRE* directory? I'd expect it to be in the JDK `lib` directory. For example, on my machine I have:

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lib\tools.jar
```

If Ant can't find it, make sure you're running the version of Java in the JDK directory rather than the one in the JRE directory.

Comment: ya found it accidently looked in the jre insted of the jdk dir

Answer (score 3):

I think your JAVA_HOME points to the JRE and not to the JDK.

tools.jar is present in the lib folder - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdkfiles.html

Answer (score 3):

Please check your Environment variables:
JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH should points to JDK not JRE

eg.

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25;

CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib;

and path should points to JDK bin

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;