# Unable to Run HDFS on MESOS Framework : Could not find or load main class org.apache.mesos.hdfs.scheduler.Main

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, mesos

I tried to follow the steps mentioned in https://github.com/mesosphere/hdfs.

When i run `./bin/hdfs-mesos` i get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.apache.mesos.hdfs.scheduler.Main

Does anyone know how i can resolve this error?

Comment: What exactly have you done. Are you in proper directory?

Comment: Yes I run ./bin/hdfs-mesos by going in the particular directory.

Comment: What's in `./lib`?

Comment: nothing... ./lib is empty... That's the issue I suppose as the script in hdfs-mesos uses the jars at this location.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run mesos-hdfs it needs to be build. github repo contains only source same tagged releases.

**Follow this steps:**

```
git clone git@github.com:mesosphere/hdfs.git
cd hdfs
git checkout 0.1.6
./bin/build-hdfs
cd build/hdfs-mesos-0.1.6
./bin/hdfs-mesos
```

You can replace `git` commands with downloading tarball with desired release

```
wget https://github.com/mesosphere/hdfs/archive/0.1.6.tar.gz
tar -xvf 0.1.6.tar.gz
cd hdfs-0.1.6 
./bin/build-hdfs
cd build/hdfs-mesos-0.1.6
./bin/hdfs-mesos
```

Comment: Now when trying the said steps on doing ./bin/build-hdfs got the below mentioned error :
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mesos-commons:compileJava'.
> Could not find tools.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: Did you changed dir to `build/hdfs-mesos-0.1.6`

Comment: I followed these steps : wget https://github.com/mesosphere/hdfs/archive/0.1.6.tar.gz
tar -xvf 0.1.6.tar.gz
cd hdfs-0.1.6 
./bin/build-hdfs and at this step got the error as mentioned

Comment: It's a problem form Gradle. Do you have JDK installed properly? Check your `JAVA_HOME` env variable. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11265727/1387612) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11345708/1387612) answer for similar problem.

Comment: Cool get familiar with [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved by following the steps :

```
wget https://github.com/mesosphere/hdfs/archive/0.1.6.tar.gz
tar -xvf 0.1.6.tar.gz
cd hdfs-0.1.6 
./bin/build-hdfs
cd build/hdfs-mesos-0.1.6
./bin/hdfs-mesos
```

Also had changed `JAVA_HOME` to jdk

Comment: did you install hdfs before ? I´m having exact the same thing.